# if any element in two arrays matches then return true?

Tags: php

I've two arrays, one is my define array and another I process from the database. Is there any proper way to compare between those arrays?

From database:

```
$user_type = [0 => "public" 1 => "10x413" 2 => "12x432"]
```

Defined array:

```
$specificUser = ['10x410','10x411','10x412','10x413','10x414']
```

If any element matches, then return true, just like php `in_array()` function.

Comment: Show an example of the two arrays that have a common element.

Comment: I've processed this array from database, $user_type =  [
  0 => "public"
  1 => "10x413"
  2 => "12x432"] , and $specificUser =  ['10x410','10x411','10x412','10x413','10x414'] this is my own define array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop and check as you would using `in_array()` to get the value that matches:

```
foreach($specificUser as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $user_type)) {
        echo $value;
        //break; to stop checking, a match was found, or not to continue and see more
    }
}
```

Or to just test for any match:

```
if(array_intersect($specificUser, $user_type)) {
    // it's true :-)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been asked and answered before, but here's a solution:

```
array() !== array_intersect($user_types, $specific_users);
```

*Note:* The array elements are compared using strict comparison, so two elements are considered matching only if they are the same type *and* value.